# How to execute function on Navigator pop from a nested stateless widget

Tags: flutter

[image]

- I have an UI like the image. The `listView` is generate from data coming from `FutureBuilder -> future`.
- Each item in the list is a `ListTile` and the red marked part is another stateless widget that navigates to another page do do some update operation.
- I am going from one screen to another using `Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(screenName)`.
- If I want to do some operation when then `Navigator.of(context).pop()` then I can use
  `Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(AddFamilyMember.routeName).then((value) => {})`
- But I can not perform it from a `list item` in the `list`
- So how to do it?

[image]

- The code would be too complicated that is why I am drawing this image
- So according to the image when I come back from screen 4 to screen 2 I can call `Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(AddFamilyMember.routeName).then((value) => {})`
- I want to do the same when I come back from screen 6 to screen 2
- Please note image 3 is not a screen . this widget represent one list item from the list view
- Marked 7 is the widget that takes to screen 6
- So how to do it?

Comment: Can you please share code? so we can understand what actually you are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

what you can do here when you naviagte to other screen make your navigation as async and save the vale in variable  the based on this variable you can perform a funtion .....

```
     onTap: () async {
        var result = await Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
            Routes.inviteFamilyMember,
            arguments: {'data': null});

        if (result == "Update") {
          _refreshIndicatorKey.currentState.show();
        }
      }
```

on poping back retun value true or false based on this value trigger the refresh indicator still have doubts let me know